# Скачивание файла без прямого обращения

Tags: php, zip, download

Здравствуйте

на сервере есть папка sources, на нее установлен запрет для прямого обращения, то есть если перейти по адресу site.com/sources получим ошибку 403

В этой папке лежат архивы zip

Как средствами PHP можно скачать файл к примеру site.com/sources/file.zip без прямого обращения к файлу?

прошу помощи в реализации!

Comment: Без прямого обращения к файлу - вероятно никак, потому что непонятно что запрашивается. 403 на каталог не всегда означает 403 для файлов в нем, по полному пути, может, получится слить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function file_force_download($file) {
  if (file_exists($file)) {
    // сбрасываем буфер вывода PHP, чтобы избежать переполнения памяти выделенной под скрипт
    // если этого не сделать файл будет читаться в память полностью!
    if (ob_get_level()) {
      ob_end_clean();
    }
    // заставляем браузер показать окно сохранения файла
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    // читаем файл и отправляем его пользователю
    readfile($file);
    exit;
  }
}
```

Здесь `$file` - путь к файлу (например, "sources/file.zip"). [Источник и другие способы](https://m.habrahabr.ru/post/151795/)

Добавление по безопасности от заботливого @TotalPusher

> Добавить проверку на `../`, или берите только имя файла `pathinfo($_GET['file'], PATHINFO_BASENAME)`, и на одну уязвимость будет меньше.

Comment: Плохо с точки зрения безопасности. Так можно вытащить все файлы сайта, а если нет ограничения `open_basedir` - то и многие файлы системы. Поэтому поправьте, пожалуйста, ответ, добавив проверку на `../`, или берите только имя файла `pathinfo($_GET['file'], PATHINFO_BASENAME)`, и на одну уязвимость будет меньше.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте полный путь ввести, если все запросы не слиты на определённый файл, то может получиться хоть и 403